# Could not find driver for Laravel [Cent OS 6]

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, centos

I tried `sudo yum install php54w-pdo --enablerepo=remi` to install PDO driver in centos 6.

It installed successfully. But exception is raised by laravel 
`PDOException in Connector.php line 47: could not find driver`

Did everything i can. Tried different solution from stackoverflow. but didn't work.

Comment: "yum install php54w-pdo --enablerepo=remi" doesn't make sense. php54w-* comes from "webtatic", not from "remi"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also need to install pdo driver for the database you are using. `php-pdo` alone is not sufficient as it is mostly abstraction layer and to be able to connect to particular database it yet needs a right driver (i.e. `php54w-mysqlnd` which would provide `pdo-mysql` driver).

Comment: For all extensions "yum install php-<extname>" could be used, whatever is the package which provides it  (so yum install php-pdo_mysql in this case). Packages layout have changed, and could change again.